# How to remove the titlebar in Gnome 3.20 under the Arc Dark theme?

Tags: gnome3, gtk, window-decorations, mutter

How to set `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` so that it removes/shrinks-to-zero window titlebars in Gnome 3.20.4 under the Arc Dark theme?

I'm looking about getting windows without the decorations.